# (VS Code) Pylint throws a syntax error when importing a module but works perfectly fine when I run my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module

The module I am trying to import is `pyinputplus`. I do not know why it shows an error if the program imports the module and uses all of its functionality just fine.

This is the error message:

```
Cannot import 'pyinputplus' due to syntax error 'invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 268)'pylint(syntax-error)
```

I can do with it because it does not impair functionality but it really annoys me and distracts me when working in my IDE. Plus, it could be a sign that something is not setup right.

Comment: Please provide the part of the code that's supposed to contain the error (i.e. around line 268). You say it works fine when you run your code, but throws an error when importing - importing from where and how?

Comment: @Grismar My code is 105 lines long, so I guess line 268 refers to the module/library  I "pip installed". On the __init__ file of the module I see that line 268 is a comment so there´s no way that is wrong. Maybe I´m not checking in the right place.

Comment: The issue would be in pyinputplus - you're using https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus/? Did you obtain it through `pip install`? When does the error occur exactly? Where are you seeing it? Have you configured your IDE to use the same virtual environment you installed the package into?

Comment: @Grismar Yes. Yes I obtained it through pip install. I am seeing a red underline under the "import" in the very first line. When I put my cursor over it it shows a box with the message I detailed above. No (at least not manually), how can I do that?

Comment: Have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments?

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I had gone through that before. I changed the recommended settings in the settings.json file but still nothing changes

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the order of the lines in the file.

The type of the function `inputStr()` is recognized correctly

`.....` means [snip] of the line(s)

```
def inputStr(
    prompt="",
    .....):
    # type: (str, .....) -> Any
    """Prompts the user to enter .....
    """
```

For `inputCustom()` the type recognition is incorrect because the type line is incorrect

```
def inputCustom(
    # type: (Callable, str, .....) -> Any
    customValidationFunc,
    prompt="",
    .....):
    """Prompts the user to enter input. ....."""
```

it should be AFTER the argument list.

```
def inputCustom(
    customValidationFunc, prompt="", .....):
    # type: (Callable, str, .....) -> Any
    """Prompts the user to enter input. ....."""
```

Do the same for the function `inputNum()`

You can edit the `__init__.py` file and move the 2 comment lines to the correct position.

Then VSC will show the type in the tooltip.

I have created an [Issue at pyinputplus](https://github.com/asweigart/pyinputplus/issues/12) for it.

---

**Edit:**

I have looked at why pylint shows this cryptic error and the problem is that the Python3.8 compiler reports this as a syntax error when you compile with `type_comments=True`. Pylint first tries to compile with `type_comments=True` but does not test the Python3.8 exception correct.

I have written a [replacement for `astroid/builder.py::_parse_string()`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3757#issuecomment-692585830). The line is not reported as an error anymore. Maybe when they use the rewrite, they will add an error for a misplaced type annotation.

Comment: I moved the comment in inputCustom and inputNum exactly to the position of the comment in inputString. However, my issue was not resolved. It still shows an error in my other documents. I am no Python expert, but why would it matter where a comment is placed? Should I uncomment that line?

Comment: I had to install `pylint` to reproduce your error. After I move the line to the correct location the error from `pylint` disappeared. For pylint the location of the comment line with parameter type info is wrong. You need to execute the command `Python: Run Linter` to get the error gone, or modify your source file and save it.

Comment: thank you for your input, but reproducing those steps does not solve my issue.

Comment: @MarcoTagliani Show us a minimal source code that has the problem you have. Just showing the error message is not enough.

Comment: I did not understand your edit. What is asteroid/builder.py ? How can I implement that parse string function in pyinputplus to solve my issue?

Comment: just like `pylint` is a python module so is `asteroid`. `pylint` uses `asteroid`, locate the `builder.py` file in the `asteroid` module. the location depends on if you use virtual environments and where on the OS Python is installed. Look of `python` executable and from there search in the `Lib` subdirectory

Comment: Implementing your parse string function instead of the original in the builder module does not resolve the issue.

Comment: post the source code with the error, or a minimal version that has the error

Comment: there´s really not much to post.It shows the "error" under the keyword import in the first line by underlining it. The first line being "import pyinputplus". It does not matter what comes after cause that is where the error lies.

Comment: just edit the correct `__init__.py` and move the two comment lines and the problem is solved, if it still complains about the same line number you edit the wrong file, look for the correct pyinputplus module you use, use `F12` on the error.

Comment: Hello, I'm the creator of pyinputplus. Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the type hints typo as of PyInputPlus 0.2.11. Please upgrade by running pip install -U pyinputplus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of PyInputPlus. Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the type hints typo as of PyInputPlus 0.2.11. The solution is to upgrade by running `pip install -U pyinputplus`.